# How to make + work in sed's regexps on FreeBSD?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, freebsd

Consider the following typescript:

```
$ freebsd-version
10.0-RELEASE-p5
$ echo ' found' | sed -n '/[[:blank:]]\+/p'
$ echo ' found' | grep '[[:blank:]]\+'
 found
```

When I do this on Arch Linux with GNU `sed`:

```
$ echo ' found' | sed -n '/[[:blank:]]\+/p'
 found
$ echo ' found' | grep '[[:blank:]]\+'
 found
```

Am I doing it wrong? Why doesn't it work on FreeBSD? How to make it work?

Comment: Did you read your sed manpage? I'd try removing the backslash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** see [fd0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233115/29867)'s solution

I did look in the man page before asking, but failed to notice the relevant info, since I figured it doesn't differ significantly from that of Linuxes. But,

```
$ man sed
...
 -E      Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular
         expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The
         re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.
$ man re_format
...
 Obsolete (“basic”) regular expressions differ in several respects.  ‘|’
 is an ordinary character and there is no equivalent for its functional‐
 ity.  ‘+’ and ‘?’ are ordinary characters, and their functionality can be
 expressed using bounds (‘{1,}’ or ‘{0,1}’ respectively).  Also note that
 ‘x+’ in modern REs is equivalent to ‘xx*’.  The delimiters for bounds are
 ‘\{’ and ‘\}’, with ‘{’ and ‘}’ by themselves ordinary characters.
```

And I did try to use `{1,}`, I just forgot to escape curly brackets. So surely [fd0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233115/29867)'s solution is generally the best way possible. But others would be:

```
$ echo ' found' | sed -n '/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/p'
 found
$ echo ' found' | sed -n '/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/p'
 found
```

However, not sure what they meant by

> Also note that ‘x+’ in modern REs is equivalent to ‘xx*’

Meaning, what it was like in nonmodern ones.

Also, `grep`'s manpage didn't mention `re_format` entry, which apparently means it has its own implementation of regular expressions. For that matter, it was GNU `grep`, as opposed to `sed`.

Answer (score 4):

With BSD sed you have to turn on ERE's with the `E` option.

```
echo '  found' | sed -nE '/[[:blank:]]+/p'
```